# Is the mass an eigenvalue of Dirac equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, vectors, dirac-equation, eigenvalue

Writing the Dirac equation as:

$$(i \hbar\gamma^{\mu}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}})\psi = m \psi$$

it seems that $m$ is an eigenvalue of the operator of the left side, and we need to find the eigenvectors $\psi$.

But is there only one eigenvalue? And $\psi$ is not a vector, but a spinor. Is the notion of an eigenvector still valid?

Comment: Sure, I guess that's technically true. Of course you can think of it this way, as "eigenvectors" need only be elements of a vector space -- which spinors are.

Comment: Be careful, the derivative involved is $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}$, not $\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu}$.

Comment: @doublefelix thank you, I corrected.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that there is not "one" eigenvalue, but at least 3 (for the leptons, which are more closely described by the free hamiltonian, we could add quarks but those cannot be described by a quantum theory of asymptotic eigenstates). There could be more than 3 if neutrinos turn out to have mass (which they most likely have)

The caveat is that we don't know how to interpret or measure things like a superposition of an electron and a muon, those superpositions are banned by ad-hoc rules called [Superselection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superselection)